# Is it possible to prevent the destructor from running when calling delete in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management

Specifically, in a library, I have a memory pool that overrides the behaviour of new and delete for certain classes. I want users of the library to be able to call delete on instances of those classes, but I need to keep the instances alive until a specific cleanup action at a later time. Is this at all possible while letting the users use regular new/delete? Some way to override the default behaviour of calling the destructor?

Comment: @blgt there is a difference between `operator delete` which is the function used for memory deallocation and the `delete` operator which is the special keyword translated by the compiler into "destructor call and memory deallocation via `operator delete`". So overloading the function won't stop the compiler from calling the destructor.

Comment: @ArneMertz Right, my bad for not reading the question carefully enough

Comment: Something off the top of my head if you have control over these classes is to use a combination of CRTP+non-virtual destructors to achieve what you want and do all the cleanup you need yourself from a base class. Not sure if I understood the question correctly though.

Comment: Just implement the destructor for your objects to not delete the resources until your cleanup action has occurred

Comment: @EdChum, that will keep the object's resources around but not the object itself. The object's lifetime will still have ended when its destructor runs, making any use of it undefined. It's not clear from the question whether that's good enough to solve the problem, "I need to keep the instances alive" implies it isn't.

Comment: @JonathanWakely that would be mitigated by using a smart pointer like your answer states, you are correct. Need further clarification of the usage semantics from the OP.

Comment: The instance needs to remain usable until the later cleanup action, so I'm afraid an empty destructor doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no. 
Calling `delete` *always* triggers a call to the destructor, and after that a call to `operator delete`, the same way as calling `new` first calls the corresponding `operator new` and then runs the constructor of the object.
If you want to prevent your users from destroying the objects you have to somehow prevent them from a) calling delete on raw pointers and b) construct them on the stack.

If you want to keep the instances alive it sounds like *you* want to manage their lifetimes, so the natural way would be to also create the objects inside your library in the first place. In addition, having plain `delete` calls in the code is considered bad style these days anyway, as there are smart pointers available who do those calls automatically.

So what you could do is add creator functions to your library which return some kind of smart pointers. Those could be either `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`s with a special deleter which does not really delete the object but pass it back to your library to be cleaned up later.

Comment: +1, the creator functions make it harder for users to create unmanaged instances of these types, helping to ensure they are always correctly managed by the smart pointer type and so will be disposed of correctly.

Comment: However, I would prefer to use `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter rather than just have one copy of the `shared_ptr` in the bookkeeping parts, otherwise users who have a `weak_ptr` can resurrect an object which is supposed to have gone away and been staged for cleanup. That complicates the cleanup code (it needs to check if the `shared_ptr` is really unique, which is hard in a multi-threaded program) and it means the OP's custom lifecycle for these objects is visible to users (they can tell that objects don't really die, they just go to a better place ;-)

Comment: @JonathanWakely imo object creation and destruction should be as symmetric as possible, meaning both should occur in the same place in symmetric ways. So if I dispose of an object by just throwing it into the library, I should have gotten it from that same library.

Comment: @JonathanWakely good point about the stored `shared_ptr`s, updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use smart pointers instead of `new`/`delete` (which is good practice anyway).

Use a custom deleter that moves ownership of the object to a list of "waiting to be cleaned up" objects.

For examples of smart pointers, refer to [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Another option (which is more work and harder to get right) is to only store the objects in containers that use custom allocators, and have the allocator's `destroy` and `deallocate` functions do the "move to a staging area for cleanup instead of actually destroying it" part. I would recommend the smart pointer with custom deleter approach, not the allocator one.

Both these options (custom deleters and custom allocators) allow you to control the exact behaviour when an object is "destroyed", separating the actual end of the object's lifetime from the moment when users dispose of it, which cannot be done with the `delete` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` runs destructors. This is a basic fact everybody relies upon. If you could somehow disable destructor calling, which you cannot, you would break everybody's expectations. If you don't want your users to invoke destructors, don't make the destructors available to them. A protected destructor will make `delete` uncallable.